# Is there a Bootstrap class for things to disappear on mobile only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

`.sr-only` the CSS class of the Bootstrap library is used to make things disappear on computer screens only. Is there any opposite **class** for it to make things disappear on mobiles only?

I know there could be several workarounds using Javascript scripts. These are acceptable if and only if there is no opposite.

Comment: `sr-only` is a class used to hide text which is placed for *screen readers*. It is not visible on computer screens *or* mobiles. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3. You really should be using the Bootstrap [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't think `.sr-only` does what you think it does. The `.hidden-xs` class that is built into bootstrap is probably what you want: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: @sdsanders isn't there any for extra small and small? I mean visible on xs and s and hidden on md and lg ?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - yes, you just apply multiple classes. `class="visible-xs visible-sm"`

Comment: @sdsanders post that as answer so that I could accept it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap responsive utilities will handle this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Hide on extra small screens screens (less than 768px):

```
class="hidden-xs"
```

Show on extra small and small screens (less than 992px):

```
class="visible-xs visible-sm"
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Bootstrap 4 you could use `class="d-md-none"`. As this would set `display:none` to the element from the md width and up.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display the element only on large and medium screens and hide on small and extra-small screens this are the classes you have to add in the element using bootstrap v4: `d-none d-md-block`.

Here is the full answer for your question if you are using Bootstrap v4:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/#responsive-utilities

Comment: This also applies in Bootstrap 5.

Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/