# Text will not highlight and :hover does not work

Tags: html, css

On the following page, http://duncanmorley.com/ there are the following issues:

- One cannot highlight text within the document
- When a user hovers over an object with the ":hover" property applied,in the CSS file, the hover effect doesn't happen (See social icons at the top) (class="fb")

It seems that there is a transparent object over the page which is not allowing the user to interact with the elements. I'm unsure what this is, as there is nothing in the CSS file (that I can see) that suggests this is the issue.

I believe these issues are likely the result of one problem.

Comment: What browser/os are you looking at it in? I briefly viewed it on Firefox/PC and seemed to work fine in regards to text highlighting and hovering over first facebook icon.

Comment: this is chrome on mac os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-indent: -99999999px;` causes the issue here because it will modify the area hover works, too.

**Fix for the Facebook share button (an example)**

Remove the `text-indent` style from the `fb` class and change `<li class="fb">Facebook</li>` to `<li class="fb"><span class="hide">Facebook</span></li>`

Now you can style the text the [`sr-only` way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758620/1540350):

```
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

At the end you should get the same effect, the "Facebook" text will be hidden for the visual presence and the hover effect will work on the entire element.

Comment: This is hugely odd. By having an text indent that's too large, I caused 1)The text on my web page not to be selectable and made the :hover function not work.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, your text-indent is too large. If you make it -9999999px instead, Chrome seems to like it better.