# Make link shown only on hover 508 compliant

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, section508

Let's say I have a list of things. When you hover over one, a "more info" link appears beside it.

What treatment can I apply to the link to make it 508 compliant and/or always visible for screen readers?

Comment: 3 votes to close and no comments indicating why. How can I make this question more clear or appropriate?

Comment: I would guess the close votes are because this is previously treaded territory. You might have better luck moving this to the UX/UI stackoverflow community since it isn't really a CSS question.

Comment: You may want to checkout the "sr-only" class in Bootstrap 3 or this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3.