# Trigger the file input prompt with a hidden label element - Safari

Tags: html, css, label

I have the code:

```html
<label name="xs" id="xs" for="fileselect">
  <p class="add_atach">Test</p>
</label>
<input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" style="display:none;" />
```

If I leave `display:none;` on-click nothing happens. If I change it to `visibility:hidden;`, the code works but the space occupied by the element remains. What to should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern browsers will trigger the file `input` element to open even when the element is hidden with `display: none`; but as you have noticed, this doesn't work in Safari. In addition it also doesn't work in IE8 and below.

As a workaround, here are [two alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button/25825731#25825731) solutions that should work in all cases.

The easiest option would be to set the positioning of the element to `fixed` and then position it off the screen using a combination of `right: 100%`/`bottom: 100%`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8x2fobw/)

```
input[type="file"] {
    position: fixed;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

You could also use the CSS that is [commonly used to visually hide content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3) but allow it to remain visible for screen readers:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lzjzwr7/)

```
input[type="file"] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Both of these options effectively hide the `input` element without usage of `display: none`.