# Screenreader shall read aria-label and ignore label with for attribute

Tags: html, forms, wai-aria, screen-readers

I am currently working on an html form with proper disability access. I have inputs labelled by labels with the for-attribute. But now I want one input getting a different text for the screenreader than the label displays:

```
<div class="cc_form_w50 t5">
  <label id="lbl_city" for="input_city">City / Town</label>
</div>
<div class="cc_form_w50 t5">
  <input type="text" required name="city" title="City / Town" placeholder="Enter your city or town" class="w100" id="input_city">
</div>
```

The screenreader ready the "/" as symbol in the system language, so I want to make the screenreader "or" instead, like the title or placeholder. As long as I use the "for"-attribute or "aria-labelledby" the text of the label is read. Any "aria-label"-attribute is ignored by the reader.

Without the "for"-attribute the cursor doesn't enter the input by selecting the label.

Is it possible to tell the screenreader to read something else than the content of the label-tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to fix it.

The first hides the '/' from screen readers (using `aria-hidden`) then adds visually hidden text that is read by screen readers.  You can do a google search on the `sr-only` class.  It comes from bootstrap but lots of other frameworks define it too.  You can copy the definition of the class from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3).

```
<div>
  <label for="input_city">City <span aria-hidden="true">/</span> <span class="sr-only">or</span> Town</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" required name="city" placeholder="Enter your city or town" id="input_city">
</div>
```

Another way to fix it (and this is a little simpler) is to hide the label completely (again, using `aria-hidden`) from the screen reader then specify an `aria-label` on the `<input>`.

```
<div>
  <label for="input_city" aria-hidden="true">City / Town</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" required name="city" placeholder="Enter your city or town" id="input_city" aria-label="city or town">
</div>
```

Both solutions still allow the mouse user to click on the label and have it move the focus to the `<input>` field.

I also removed the `title` (tooltip) attribute because it seemed overkill having a label, a placeholder, and a tooltip.  Plus, some screen readers **incorrectly** include the tooltip in the name of the label when it's read, so sometimes you still hear the '/' in the label if you have the tooltip.  (The tooltip is the *last* attribute examined when determining the accessible name of an element.  See step 2I in the "[Accessible Name and Description Computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2)")

Comment: Thanks a lot, both work in a way, but the first one creates a quite diffusing reading, while reading the label. It ready just "City" and "Town" when click on it, not the whole label. So I go with the second approach, that a click on the label moves the cursor into the input, but therefore always reads the text as expected.