# Making a step progress indicator accessible for screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility

I often need to use a step indication to display the step the user is on, or the progress of a package in transit, etc.

Like this:
[image]

This is made up of an unordered HTML list.

```
        <ul class="progress-tracker progress-tracker--text progress-tracker--center">
          <li class="progress-step is-complete">
            <span class="progress-marker"></span>
            <span class="progress-text">
              <h4 class="progress-title">Step 1</h4>
              Summary text explaining this step to the user
            </span>
          </li>

          <li class="progress-step is-complete">
            <span class="progress-marker"></span>
            <span class="progress-text">
              <h4 class="progress-title">Step 2</h4>
              Summary text explaining this step to the user
            </span>
          </li>

          <li class="progress-step is-active">
            <span class="progress-marker"></span>
            <span class="progress-text">
              <h4 class="progress-title">Step 3</h4>
              Summary text explaining this step to the user
            </span>
          </li>

          <li class="progress-step">
            <span class="progress-marker"></span>
            <span class="progress-text">
              <h4 class="progress-title">Step 4</h4>
              Shorter summary text
            </span>
          </li>

          <li class="progress-step">
            <span class="progress-marker"></span>
            <span class="progress-text">
              <h4 class="progress-title">Step 5</h4>
              Shorter summary text
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Assuming a new list is loaded on each page (i.e. "step"), is there a way to adapt this for screen readers/assistive technology?

It would be nice to have the reader read the current step to the user, at least.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are the steps static or can the user click on a previous step to go back?

If the progress indicator is interactive, then enclose the whole thing in a `<nav>` element.  Your progress indicator would be similar to a [breadcrumb trail](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#breadcrumb).  The `<nav>` should also have an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-label) and the current step in the process should have [`aria-current`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-current).  So it might look something like:

```
<nav aria-label="progress">
  <ul class="progress-tracker progress-tracker--text progress-tracker--center">
    <li class="progress-step is-complete">
      ...
    </li>

    <li class="progress-step is-complete">
        ...
      </li>

    <li class="progress-step is-active" aria-current="true">
        ...
      </li>

    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

However, your code snippet didn't include any links so I'm guessing your progress indicator is static and not interactive.  In that case, don't use a `<nav>`, because you can't navigate with your indicator, but you could still group the elements together.  Having an unordered list is a type of grouping, but sometimes a screen reader will not read the `aria-label` on a list.

```
<ul aria-label="progress">
```

You could work around the issue by having:

```
<div role="group" aria-label="progress">
  <ul>
    <li>
      ...
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(essentially replacing the `<nav>` in the first example with `<div role="group">`.

Since your progress indicator is a series of steps, using an ordered list `<ol>` would have better semantic information.  You can style the list so the default numbers of a `<ol>` are not displayed (similar to how you're not showing bullet points with the `<ul>`).

And finally, I would add some "hidden" text for the screen reader to say if the step is completed or not.  Visually, you have blue circles for completed steps, an open circle for the active step, and gray circles for not completed.  That's all done with CSS (your "is-complete" and "is-active" classes).  That same context should be conveyed to screen readers.  The open circle ("is-active") is conveyed with the `aria-current` attribute.  Use a "sr-only" type class to add text for a screen reader.  (See  [What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3))

```
<div role="group" aria-label="progress">
  <ol class="progress-tracker progress-tracker--text progress-tracker--center">
    <li class="progress-step is-complete">
      <span class="sr-only">completed</span>
      ...
    </li>

    <li class="progress-step is-complete">
      <span class="sr-only">completed</span>
      ...
    </li>

    <li class="progress-step is-active" aria-current="true">
      ...
    </li>

    <li class="progress-step">
      <span class="sr-only">not completed</span>
      ...
    </li>
    ...
  </ol>
</div>
```

In summary, the minimal changes you need are to:

- maybe switch from `<ul>` to `<ol>`
- add "sr-only" text to the "completed" and "not completed" items
- add `aria-current` to the current step

Comment: Great explanation. For the non-interactive progress indicator: Wouldn't it be even more precise to use `aria-current="step"` for the active step? Not sure whether ScreenReaders will make any distinction between "step" and "true" within a `group`.

Comment: Not all screen readers support the "new" values for `aria-current`.  You'd have to test it.  "True" used to be the only value and then new ones were added, albeit several years ago.  Some screen readers will say "*current*" for "true" and then say "*current + [value]*" when you use a diff value for `aria-current`.  For example, `aria-current="step"` will probably say "*current step*" and `aria-current="page"` will probably say "*current page*".

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the answers that were previously added to this question.

The **correct way of identifying the current step is with `aria-current="step"`**.

While `aria-current="page"` is valid, is meant to be used in a set of links (for exemple, a breadcrumbs widget or a pagination widget).I highly recommend reading more about the [aria-current attribute](https://www.aditus.io/aria/aria-current/), including its possible values and when to use it. Your example would then look like follows:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Step 1 ... </li>
  <li>Step 2 ... </li>
  <li aria-current="step">Step 3...</li>
  <li>Step 4 ... </li>
  <li>Step 5 ... </li>
</ol>
```

Note: I also recommend you use an `<ol>` instead of an `<ul>` as this list of steps has an order.

Comment: I asked specifically about this here, I'd welcome you to weigh in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68854228/what-is-the-correct-attribute-for-the-current-step-of-a-progress-bar-aria-curre/68854229#68854229

Comment: I didn't see anyone recommend a value of "page" for `aria-current`.  And the selected answer already recommended using `<ol>`.  So what part of any of the answers did you disagree with?  It's not *wrong* to use `aria-current="true"`.  That's a minimal solution.  It might sound more semantically correct to use "step" but there's no requirement to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like any of your content is focusable. I had a similar situation that I've shipped in our angular app that works great with JAWS, NVDA, and VoiceOver. What you can do is wrap your markup in a 'div' container and screen reader specific content like this.

```
<div>
  <span class="sr-only">Step 3 of 5: Summary text explaining this step to the user</span>
   ...
</div>
```

The 'sr-only' class hides the copy from the visual UI but allows for screen readers to "see" it in the accessible tree.

```
.sr-only {
border: none;
clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 1px;
margin: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
```

}

It's important to only make the content available for the step that is currently active.

Hope this helps.