# What is the correct attribute for the current step of a progress bar, aria-current="true", or aria-current="step"?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

There's contradictory information in various tutorials across the web, as well as in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932018/making-a-step-progress-indicator-accessible-for-screen-readers), so I'm seeking some help to clarify. In contex to a step progress indicator like the one below, which way is correct value for the current step in-progress, aria-current="true", or, aria-current="step"?

[image: Image of step-based progress indicator]

Comment: Funny, I went to the "SO question" you referred to, starting reading the answer and thought, "this guy knows what he's talking about".  I was then embarrassed that it was me :-)  I typically use `aria-current="true"` because I've tested that on a variety of browsers and screen readers and know it works.  I have not tested the "step" value.  Whether the user hears "current" or "current step" probably doesn't matter.  The latter is a slightly better UX but you'd want to test on all platforms first.

Answer (score 0):

W3.org seems to show that aria-current="step" would be correct, unless the fact that the visually styled element is not a link changes this.

> A step token used to indicate a link within a step indicator for a step-based process, where the link is visually styled to represent the current step. - [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-current)