# Accessible table with expandable row

Tags: html, accessibility

I want to create a table with expandable row, where the expandable part is the row with the cell corresponding to the column, how can we make it accessible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>services</th>
          <th>period</th>
          <th>limit</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>dental</th>
          <td>no period</td>
          <td>120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandable-row">
          <td>description about dental</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Hasan. This question was already asked, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314689/make-expandable-table-rows-accessible. You’ll need to implement [the ARIA tree grid pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/treegrid/) via `role=treegrid`, `aria-expanded` attributes and the necessary keyboard control.