# aria-label on input tag does not read Android chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angular5, accessibility, wai-aria

aria-label is not being read on Android Chrome, for example:

```
<input aria-label="test" type="text">
```

On *Android chrome*, it reads "Editbox, double tap to edit, double tap to enter text".

But the same thing is read as "test, text field, double tap to edit" on *iOS chrome*.

Anyone else ever seen this issue?

Comment: Turns out this is an issue only for Samsung devices.

Comment: I believe this is the issue you filed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120171533

I'm running into the same issue on a Nexus. However, the aria-label for me is on a span tag. Have you come to any conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a blatant bug with android/chrome.  The `aria-label` attribute is a global attribute that can be used on any element (see https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#global_states).

What happens if you try `aria-labelledby`?

```
<span id="foo" style="display:none">test</span>
<input aria-labelledby="foo" type="text">
```

Will android/chrome read that?

What happens with the `<label>` element?

```
<label for="myid" class="sr-only">test</label>
<input id="myid" type="text">
```

Will android/chrome read that?

(The "sr-only" class is used to visually hide the `<label>` but it's still available for screen readers to read.  See [What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3))

Comment: Surprisingly none of them work. All of them just reads "editbox, double tap to edit"

Comment: wow, that's a serious issue for android.  do you have a way to report a bug to them?  i'm assuming you're using talkback?  do you have another browser on android to test?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Talkback. Firefox on Android has the same issue. I opened an issue on Google Issue Tracker, we'll see where this goes.