# '.' between upper case letters are not reading in accessibility voice over

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a similar text `XYZ.CO.IN` given as aria-label for one of the link given in my web page. While doing the accessibility testing, it is reading as

> XYZ CO IN

It is avoiding '.' between the sentences. What should be work around for this ? Does anyone has any idea about it ? I wanted it to read the complete sentence including '.'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default VoiceOver settings then the verbosity for punctuation is set to "some".  Go to

```
Settings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Verbosity > Punctuation
```

and set it to "All".  Then you'll hear the periods in the string.

Comment: This might be something which I missed ( The configuration changes ). But, I need a more `code` specific solution for this issue.

Comment: Somewhat related, see my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547488/pronounce-abbreviations-or-initialisms-as-individual-characters-in-androids-talk/53547759#53547759.  If you already have an `aria-label`, you could brute force it by having `aria-label="X Y Z dot C O dot I N"` but that has an adverse affect on braille users.

Answer (score 0):

Users are typically familar with the way their screen reader announces domain names.  Various screen readers have user settings to control verbosity, including some for punctuation.

As an author (or developer) you shouldn't try to force a screen reader to announce the punctuation. It's their screen reader, not yours.

Note that an aria-label is conveyed to assistive technology in general - it isn't just for text-to-speech output. These labels are also conveyed via  Braille displays too, and can also affect how speech control (dictation input) behaves. Beware of trying to use ARIA to influence how a link *sounds* in a screen reader, because you can make things worse for braille output and speech control users.

Answer (score -1):

Adding coma between the dots is a potential work-around for this issue. A possible solution could be changing `aria-label` as `XYX,.CO,.IN`.

Comment: I strongly advise against this for two reasons. First, the commas will be output via Braille displays, and may make it seem like a comma-separated list. Second, it could make it hard for a speech control user to activate the link. Beware of an `aria-label` which differs from the visible link text. See WCAG "Label in name" - https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html