# iPhone VoiceOver doesn't pronounce text for the arrow

Tags: html, focus, accessibility, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader

I have this tested page http://fiddle.jshell.net/wt3dqm8b/1/show/light/ (which might be edited here https://jsfiddle.net/wt3dqm8b/1/).

Unfortunately, when you visit it from iPhone with turned on VoiceOver (`Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> VoiceOver ON`), you hear "Link One link" for the "Link One" link (which is good), but do NOT hear the same "Link One link" when you tap on the ">" arrow. Only "link" pronounced when you click on the ">" arrow.
Many ways were tried, but no one worked fine.

**How to change the html code so that the same text "Link One link" pronounced when you click on the ">" arrow?**

Here is the code from the page above:

**HTML:**

```
<ul  class="master secondary">
  <li  aria-expanded="false" class="main" tabindex="0" aria-label="Link One">
   <a  tabindex="-1" href="https://google.com">
   <span ><span > Link One </span></span>
   <i  class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li  aria-expanded="false" class="main" tabindex="0" aria-label="Link Two">
   <a  tabindex="-1" href="https://google.com">
   <span ><span > Link Two </span></span>
   <i  class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and **CSS:**

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
}


.master {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.master .main {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.master .main>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: green; 
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: 15px;
}

.master .main > a .fa-angle-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

P.S. Of course I don't want to change the html code significantly, so that:

- no significant changes are expected for JAWS screen reader,
- the same behavior kept for the keyboard used - the whole navigation items get focused only once when the Tab key used, no changes in this behavior please.

**UPDATE:**
Even in the code below

```
<ul  class="master secondary">
  <li aria-expanded="false" class="main">
   <a  target="_self" href="https://google.com">
   <span ><span > Link One </span></span>
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right" title="Time to destination by car"><span class="sr-only">This text is not pronounced with VoiceOver - why?</span></i>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li aria-expanded="false" class="main">
   <a target="_self" href="https://google.com">
   <span ><span > Link Two </span></span>
   <span class="fa fa-angle-right" title="Time to destination by car"><span class="sr-only">This text is not pronounced with VoiceOver - why?</span></span>
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I really don't understand why your code is so complicated. Why do you need `tabindex` on `li` when you only have a focusable element (`a` with `href` attribute) inside it? Why does `li` have an `aria-label`, especially one that duplicates the link text? Why do the links need `target="_self"`? To put it harshly, all of that looks like redundant cruft.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe You're right, I've updated the code above by removing target="_self", as it is not related to this question (the code was simplified). For another things... Do you have a suggestion how to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe, I've added another example with sr-only class  (at the very end of my question) and based on your comment. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your updated code with your CSS and the "sr-only" class from [What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3) and it worked fine with VoiceOver.  I'm running iOS 12.1.2 on my iPhone.

I heard "this text is not pronounced..." when navigating to the link.

Everything contained within the <a> was treated as one "tab stop" in VoiceOver so I couldn't swipe specifically to the ">" arrow.  That's the behavior I'd expect.  You should **not** make the ">" arrow a separate link or tab stop if "link one" has the same destination (`href`) as the ">" arrow.

Comment: I agree with you that I should not make the ">" arrow a separate link or tab stop if "link one" has the same destination (href) as the ">" arrow.  And I don't do that as you see per my code suggested: a href wraps everything.   Testing your result. Thank YOU for your help.

Comment: I have updated the iOS to 12.1.2 and pasted the updated code here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wt3dqm8b/9/show/light/  I believe this is the code that you've tried, right?  It doesn't pronounce for me "this text is not pronounced...". Just the "link".  The code itself may be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/wt3dqm8b/9/  Something is still missed.

Comment: I just tried your new http://fiddle.jshell.net/wt3dqm8b/9/show/light/ and it's working fine for me.  I again hear the "this text is not pronounced..." when I swipe right until I get to the link.  And the ">" doesn't show as a separate swipe.