# ng-bootstrap rating showing unwanted brackets

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap, angular-material-6

I am trying to implement a **Rating system** for book reading. I have the rating component working on the form but I see `(*)` adjacent to the stars. Not sure where they came from.

[image]

So when I hover both the star and the asterisk in the brackets are marked simultaneously. I am trying to implement the example from [ng-bootstrap.github](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples)

Here's part of the code for **list.component.html**

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="rating">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Rating</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <app-rating></app-rating>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

Here's the code for **rating.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rating',
  templateUrl: './rating.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rating.component.css']
})
export class RatingComponent {

  currentRate = 1;
}
```

I am using `ng-bootstrap 4.0.2` and `angular-material 7.3.0`.

**Edit**: Adding code for **rating.component.html**

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"></ngb-rating>
```

Comment: add the `rating.component.html` code

Comment: Please provide code in rating.component.html

Comment: @Sreemat code added

Comment: @AndreiTătar code added

Answer (score 2):

You also need to include the bootstrap CSS files. The `(*)` adjacent to the stars have the `sr-only` class which means they should be hidden if the correct CSS is loaded.

[What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3)

> According to bootstrap's documentation, the class is used to hide information intended only for screen readers from the layout of the rendered page.

Make sure you installed bootstrap `npm install bootstrap --save-dev` and edit your `styles.scss` file to import the boostrap styles:

`@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

or import only the things that you need

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Comment: So the documentation https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/rating/rating.ts shows how the `(*)` is rendered. There’s also an option to override the template where I just have to a ‘ put <ng-template> as the only child of <ngb-rating> element ..’ I changed `rating.component.html` to `<ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"><ng-template></ng-template></ngb-rating>`.  But the component is unresponsive now.

Comment: @Ayubx So you want to use `ng-bootstrap` without the boostrap css?

Comment: I want to get it to work. I am not sure what to put in the css.

Comment: I will go through it thanks but my line of thought of was to add css to the `rating.component.css'

Comment: it depends how much of bootstrap you use or not... you can also import (or redefine) only what you need in that component. (the sr-only class).. or simply hide all sr-only `:host{ ::ng-deep{ .sr-only{display:none;}}}`

Comment: Yes for the moment I have all I need from bootstrap. So yes something like the css snippet you posted that just removes the `(*)`. I tried that and didn’t work. Btw if you take a look at the code for the Basic demo example at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples it’s pretty straight forward i.e no css or additional bootstrap code.