# Adding aria-label to text elements

Tags: html, css, wai-aria, screen-readers

So I have an HTML button, with 2 divs inside it - each of which displays certain text. Sample code below. I need to insert some text between the 2 divs such that it is only to be read by screen readers and isn't needed visually speaking. This is a large shared component so I can't really modify the control itself, hoping to just tweak the accessibility part:-

I tried using aria-label on div2, and arialabelledBy keeping the label text hidden on the screen (display: none).

```
<button>
    <div id="div1" >Main text here</div>
    <div id="div2" >sub text here</div>
</button>
```

In the above example, I need the screen reader to read something like:-
"Main text here, in between, sub text here". How do i represent "in between" above. I tried aria-label \ labelledBy but those get ignored by Narrator.

Comment: I would try adding an `aria-labelledby` on the button itself and point it to “div1 betweentext div2”, thus concatenating your way to the required result.

Answer (score 1):

You need the additional text in its own <div> and then use a class to visually hide the element but still allow screen readers to read it.  This is a very common practice.  See [What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3) for an example of a class that will do this.

Also check out "[Invisible Content Just for Screen Reader Users](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)" by WebAIM.

So you'd have something like:

```
<button>
    <div id="div1" >Main text here</div>
    <div class="sr-only" >in between</div>
    <div id="div2" >sub text here</div>
</button>
```