# How to deal with duplicative textual h1 if it already exists as part of a large (comic) image?

Tags: html, css, seo, semantic-markup

Suppose you have a page that displays a large comic image. For the human user, the comic image already contains the text that is to be put in h1 (the title of the comic). UX-wise, displaying this content is unnecessary and disruptive.

(Cutting out a piece of image to display it inside h1 with alt text is not possible because the image should exist as a single entity for the purposes of redistribution.)

What is the semantically correct way to let search engines know about the contents of h1 without compromising user experience?

---

### Option 1 (include but do not display h1):

```
<article id="todays-comic">
    <h1 style="display: none;">Sandwich</h1>
    <figure>
        <img src="sandwich-comic.jpg" alt="Comic about making a sandwich.">
    </figure>
</article>
```

Problems:

- for a long time has been considered very bad practice SEO-wise,
- there is no way to let the engines know of our good intentions.

### Option 2 (hide h1 under image):

```
<article id="todays-comic" style="position: relative;">
    <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 1;">Sandwich</h1>
    <figure>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 2;" src="sandwich-comic.jpg" alt="Comic about making a sandwich.">
    </figure>
</article>
```

Problems:

- engines can be smart enough to see that h1 is hidden,
- and consider that as a more ill-intentioned way to trick them than "display: none;",
- and there is no way to let the engines know of our good intentions.

### Option 3 (put h1 elsewhere and style it):

```
<article id="todays-comic">
    <figure>
        <img src="sandwich-comic.jpg" alt="Comic about making a sandwich.">
    </figure>
    <h1 class="small-and-inconspicuous">Sandwich</h1>
</article>
```

Problems:

- could still be considered misleading by engines,
- awkward flow (unless structured traditionally but then relocated with flex order, that could still be considered misleading),
- still requires display of unnecessary information.

### Option 4 (do not include an h1, add it to alt text):

```
<article id="todays-comic">
    <figure>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 2;" src="sandwich-comic.jpg" alt="Sandwich. Comic about making a sandwich.">
    </figure>
</article>
```

Problems:

- bad for SEO and semantically lacking: engines no longer understand what the h1 of the section is supposed to be.

---

Given the situation, what would be the best approach to hiding duplicative h1 content? Are there any better alternatives to these?

Comment: What would be wrong for you to use a figcaption / why h1 ? flex or grid to reorder is fine, grid can avoid position too of both element stand in the same grid cell. ... is article only holdind a picture + a title  (very short for a stand alone possible  content) ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Figcaption has the same cons as h1, but none of the pros. Without h1, main content section will have no top-level header at all, which was always considered bad. The main content section will contain a large image, full transcript of text in image, author's comment, tag content, publishing info, relevant nav, user comments. Yes, length of machine-readable content has always been an inherent issue for comics published as images.

Comment: okay, grid can avoid positionning or display:none : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwGyNXL

Comment: @G-Cyrillus So essentially, this is Option 2 (hiding one object under another) but more modern and responsive than "position: absolute". I can see how this can also be useful in certain scenarios outside this specific task, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of your second option.

It's important for semantics and accessibility (and therefore SEO) to properly mark up `<h1>` content if it exists. The `<h1>` can be hidden for sighted users, but using `display: none` will make it invisible to assistive technologies and many search engines will ignore it. A better way to hide it would be to take an approach similar to [Bootstrap's `.sr-only` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3), which *visually* hides elements without hiding them from assistive tech.

```html
<article id="todays-comic">
  <h1 class="sr-only">Sandwich</h1>
  <img src="sandwich-comic.jpg" alt="Comic about making a sandwich.">
</article>
```

```css
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0;
}
```

Without more context, it's hard to know if the `<figure>` element is helpful. Additionally, you should consider using [`aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA15.html) on the image to provide a more detailed description of the comic so that people using assistive technologies have a more equitable experience.