# How can I use aria standards to read $5.00/day as "five dollars per day"?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

When a screen reader reads the following code:
`<span aria-label="$5.00 per day">$5.00/day</span>`
It reads it as "five dollars per day five dollars per slash day".  How can I get it to just read out "five dollars per day"?

Comment: Voted to reopen because, while the other Q has similarities, it pertains to operable content (UI control labels), whereas this question is about guiding pronunciation of text strings in non-operable (browsable) content. Aria-label does not work in this situation! Also the answer to the other question fails to mention that second-guessing screenreader behavior often has detrimental effects on other kinds of AT, such as Braille devices. Finally, the W3 pronunciation task force was set up to address exactly this issue, and it could be mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an `aria-label` on a `<span>` is generally not supported.  See "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)", in particular the third last bullet point:

- *"Don't use aria-label or aria-labelledby on a span or div unless its
  given a role."*

In this case, you don't want to give the `<span>` a role because it doesn't have any semantic meaning (in your example).  A better way to do this is with visually hidden text.

```
<span>
  <span aria-hidden="true">$5.00/day</span>
  <span class="sr-only">$5.00 per day</span>
</span>
```

(See [What is sr-only in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3?rq=1) for info on the "sr-only" class).

In the code snippet above, the "$5.00/day" is hidden from the screen reader so it won't be announced.  Instead, the "$5.00 per day" will be announced.

You could make it more "minimal" and just apply the `aria-hidden` to the slash and apply `sr-only` to "per".

```
<span>$5.00<span aria-hidden="true">/</span><span class="sr-only"> per </span>day</span>
```

(Note that I have a space before and after "per" so that the generated announcement is "$5.00 per day" instead of "$5.00perday"

The code isn't as easy to read as the first example, but it's technically less code.  I suppose with more whitespace, it's more readable:

```
<span>$5.00
  <span aria-hidden="true">/</span>
  <span class="sr-only"> per </span>
day</span>
```