# VUE-js Accessibility for b-spinner -- audio announcement of data loading using Aria that REPEATS every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, accessibility, bootstrap-vue, wai-aria

I am trying to add accessibility for the audio announcement of "data loading" when a spinner is visually showing that the data is loading.
Obviously, I am looking for an audible announcement, ideally one that would automatically play WITHOUT having to click on anything. My goal is to hear the announcement automatically and have it repeat every 3 seconds while loading.

The code below does produce a working announcement automatically.
However, the goal of having it **REPEAT EVERY 3 SECONDS** (OR 10 seconds or whatever) has **NOT** been achieved.

Earlier stage: For people searching on this, I found that putting a `tabindex = "0"` into the code for that at least allowed some audio to proceed (which at that point was progress), but one has to t**ab to the element** to hear the announcement.  This can be viewed as undesirable.
Furthermore, a person recommend **not** using the `tabindex = 0` idea, please see my follow-up question: [For vuejs, using an aria label, will a screen-reader llive NVDA automatically read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817146/for-vuejs-using-an-aria-label-will-a-screen-reader-llive-nvda-automatically-re?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The element is b-spinner and example markup code would be:

```
 <b-spinner id = "myspinny" small variant="primary"
               show.bind="isLoading"
               role="alert"
               aria-busy = true;
               aria-live="assertive"
               aria-atomic="true"
               aria-label = "Data is loading.  Please wait for the load to finish."
               label="Searching, please wait for the specific data load" @click="myspinny"
               alt="Processing... please wait for the specific data load"
               title= "Data Loading"
               v-if="resultsBusy">
  </b-spinner>
```

The above markup syntax compiles, the spinner still runs, and there is a real audio announcement in NVDA (presumably a similar tool like JAWS would have the same result). However, the FINAL GOAL is to have it REPEAT EVERY 3 seconds.

Also, the above markup might have some elements that are not used/needed.

I would like to get an audio announcement at least once (achieved now), but the ultimate goal would be to have an announcement every 3 seconds that will stop when the page is loaded (much like the spinner).

NOTE:  I saw an accessibility related-web-page: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/spinner for this that recommended using a nested  element, but there isn't a real syntax  example that I saw.  Also, other similar questions on stack overflow don't deal with the b-spinner element as such but a  element.

There is a [detailed design for this here](https://pretagteam.com/question/vuejs-accessibility-for-bspinner-audio-announcement-of-data-loading-using-aria-that-repeats-every-3-seconds).  Unfortunately, as of this edit [11/15/2021], I personally can't get the solution from that link to work in my vue setup (which is vue version 2).

Comment: You might look into "aria-live" and "aria-busy". These features offer "polite" announcements or "rude" announcements based on whether your loading should interrupt what the user is currently hearing from their device. Also, 3 seconds of loading time seems rather long for all users. Perhaps you could use the Vue onload instance or preload before your vue router brings the user to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the need to try various ARIA attributes and roles but sometimes that complicates things.  When using ARIA, it's best to keep it minimal.  For example, you have `role="alert"` and `aria-live="assertive"`.  The [alert role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#alert) gives you an implicit assertive live region.

Assertive regions **might** clear other screen reader announcements. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live):

> User agents or assistive technologies **MAY** choose to clear queued changes when an assertive change occurs.

So it could be possible that you posting a message every 3 seconds might clobber other announcements.  Perhaps not likely but theoretically possible.

My general rule of thumb is to use `aria-live="polite"` unless your announcement is so important that the user needs to drop everything they're doing and listen to it.

Using pure html and not vue.js, the following will make an announcement every 3 seconds.

```
<div aria-live="polite" id="mymessage"></div>
<button onclick="myclick()">start annoying message</button>
<script>
  function myclick() {
    setInterval(myTimer, 3000);

    function myTimer() {
      document.getElementById("mymessage").innerHTML = 'still loading';
    }
  }
</script>
```

How to translate that to vue.js code, I'm not sure, sorry.  But it gives you a template of what the goal should be.

You'd want to kill the timer when you're done, obviously.

Comment: While I accepted this answer, in my system, with vue-js, I still cannot find a way to get the announcement to repeat despite spending several hours of effort on this.  While the first bounty is long-gone, if anyone wants to provide a complete vue-js answer, it would still be much appreciated.  The above answer was very helpful, however.

Comment: Can you not inject "basic" html into vue.js?  I know the sample code works.