# Strike out entire table row using <strike> tag

Tags: html, accessibility

I need to strike out the entire table row using `<strike></strike>` HTML tags. I applied the `<strike>` around the table row , but it didn't work. Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Other options I tried as shown below using CSS line-through. This works, but the accessibility technologies, won't recognize the line through I believe. So other answers answered in this forum for this question won't work in this case.

```html
<tr style="text-decoration: line-through; color:red; width:100%">
```

I've attached the sample code. I want the row 2 to be stricken out. Any way to achieve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<table style="border: 1px solid black;width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Table 1 Head 1</th>
        <th>Table 1 Head 2</th>
        <th>Table 1 Head 3</th>
        <th>Table 1 Head 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 3</td>
      <td>Row 1 Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <strike>
    <tr>
          <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
          <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
          <td>Row 2 Column 3
          </td>
          <td>Row 2 Column 4</td>
        </tr>
        </strike>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 3 Column 1</td>
          <td>Row 3 Column 2</td>
          <td>Row 3 Column 3</td>
          <td>Row 3 Column 4</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what about striking through each `<td>` individually?

Comment: In that case, each td content needs to be included inside <strike> tag. My data is in xml format, and I use xsl to transform and render the html content. The entire row is stored inside a processing instructions data content. So Whenever there is particular type of processing instruction element in the xml, that means, that row needs to be striked out indicating its been deleted. IN my case the entire tr.

Comment: From an accessibility perspective, whether you use <strike>, <s>, or <del> and put it on a <tr> or <td> will **not** help the screen reader user. While those elements have semantics, no screen readers do anything with them so the user won't know it's struck out. You'll need to provide [`sr-only`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3) type text to communicate the meaning of your struck-through text.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be semantically meaningful, you need to put a set of `<strike>` tags *inside* every `<td>`, you cannot do the entire row at once.

That said, if you want semantic meaning, use the `<s>` or `<del>` tags instead of `<strike>`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strike):

> Warning: This element is deprecated in HTML 4 and XHTML 1, and obsoleted in the HTML Living Standard. If semantically appropriate, i.e., if it represents deleted content, use `<del>` instead. In all other cases use `<s>`.

The same is true about `<s>` and `<del>` as `<strike>` - you cannot put them around the entire table row. The only content allowed inside these tags is ["Phrasing content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), including plain text and certain inline content elements (listed in the link above). This list *does not* include Table elements.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the strike tag depreciation.